# Jquery on method

Tags: jquery, jquery-on

I'm new to jquery. I've a class called "xxx" inside which am appending set of buttons with class name as "YYY" with changing id values for each button through ajax call.

For example

```
<div class="xxx">
</div> <!-- before ajax call -->



<div class="xxx">
<input type="button" class="YYY" id="1"/>
<input type="button" class="YYY" id="2"/>
<input type="button" class="YYY" id="3"/>
</div>
```

Now I've to get the id values of the buttons "on" click. So I used

```
$(document).ready(function{

$('.xxx').on('click','.yyy',function({
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
});

});
```

But this is not working. even i tried

```
$(document).ready(function{

$('.xxx').on('click','.yyy',function({
   var id = $('.yyy').attr('id');
});

});
```

which is returning value of first button on every click. Please help

Comment: wrong syntax used for jquery call back functions in your code snippet. Correct syntax is `function(){// code here}` whereas you used `function({ // code here })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `this` to refer to the clicked element:

```
var id = this.id;
```

You also have a couple of syntax errors in your `.ready()` and `.on()` functions, the correct syntax is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.xxx').on('click', '.yyy', function() {
    var id = this.id;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in `document.ready`. You missed bracket in function there `()` and in your click event....

Try this;

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
                      //---^^ ---here

 $('.xxx').on('click','.yyy',function(){
                           //--------^^---here
```

so it should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.xxx').on('click','.yyy',function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
});
```

rest your first code should work...

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos in the script:

```
$(document).ready(function{ //<----misssing '()'

$('.xxx').on('click','.yyy',function({ //<---missing ')' after function
```

You are already in the context of the selector then use `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')`:

```
$('.xxx').on('click','.yyy',function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('id'); // <---here $(this) is the clicked elem
});
```

or

```
$('.xxx').on('click','.yyy',function(){
   var id = this.id; // <---here 'this' is the clicked elem
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo error in click function

```
$('.xxx').on('click','.yyy',function({
                          ----------^

$('.xxx').on('click','.yyy',function(){ // it should be (){}
   var id = this.id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ::

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".xxx").on("click", ".YYY", function(event){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

You were using wrong syntax to fetch ID attribute of element.